# I used the try/except function to overcome it but even after using the function I still get the error

Tags: python

Im working on a project where there is an attribute error, so I used the try/except function to overcome it but even after using the function I still get the error. Help?

```
def info():
    while True:
        try:
           # something
        except AttributeError:
            print('Error')
```

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Please add the error

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  You posted about 30 lines of code to support a 5-line problem, and you failed to complete the posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit your post to add an error message. So that corresponding error can raised in except block.
If you want a generic exception then:

```
try:
    # something
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```